# Snowflake copy command to put default values in place of null

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am copying the data into snowflake table which has three columns: ID, DATA and ETL_LOAD_TIMESTAMP.

[image]

I have a column ETL_LOAD_TIMESTAMP  in snowflake of type **TIMESTAMP_TZ(9)** and I have set its default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP().

I get my data from a CSV file, which is of type:

```
ID, DATA
1, Dummy
```

I download the csv file at tmpdir location on local. I load the data of this csv into snowflake as:

```
create_cmd = "CREATE TEMPORARY STAGE teamp123 COMMENT = 'TEMPORARY STAGE FOR TEST_TABLE1 DATA LOAD'"
self.connection.execute("ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'UTC';")
self.connection.execute(create_cmd)


self.connection.execute(f"put file://tmpdir/* @temp123 PARALLEL=8")
 
self.connection.execute("COPY INTO TEST_TABLE1 FROM @temp123 PURGE = TRUE FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'CSV' field_delimiter = ',' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\"' ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = None error_on_column_count_mismatch=false SKIP_HEADER = 1)")
```

I get the values of ID and Data but the ETL_LOAD_TIMESTAMP is null.

How do I modify this copy command so that I get the default value of ETL_LOAD_TIMESTAMP which is current timestamp instead of null?

Answer (score 0):

you can use default `current_timestamp()` while defining datatypes or explicit to_timestamp

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html#current-time-current-timestamp-default-column-values

Comment: This does not answer the question IMO. This will work with insert into command but not with `copy into` command